# "main" has not been registered. I've been getting this error in my React Native code

Tags: javascript, react-native

> Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'NativeUnimoduleProxy': java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 0, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I tried clearing cache, created new expo app, stopped metro and created a new metro file and tried rerunning it but it won't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.